# Questions about the story of Noah

Tags: animals, geography, parashat-noach, mabul

There's a doubt I have about the story of Noah that I can't explain. If Noah's ark landed about 4000 years ago in what is now Turkey, how could some land animals get to places such as Australia or other islands? How can there be kangaroos in Australia, elephants in Sri Lanka, and bears in Japan? I know there must be an explanation, but this is really confusing and puzzling.

Comment: If you believe in the concept that most of the continents were fused and then separated, this is entirely possible. Many animals, esp. bear and deer, among others, can swim quite well for long idstances, too. I can personally vouch for deer being quite agile swimmers, contrary to what many people think. I've seen them on Fire Island, which is a good distance from "mainland" Long Island.

Comment: 1) The separation of the continents (most probably) happened during the mabul, not after. 2) how could a kangaroo swim three thousand kilometers in the ocean...?

Comment: There was another tremendous natural disaster in the days of Peleg. We see that people lived half as long from his days on.

Comment: Just say that it was part of the miracle. If that's your only concern I don't see why you wouldn't accept that answer. But I think a better question would be on the distribution of animals and why it only matches where the animals would be if they could get there naturally and where similar pre-flood-era fossils were. For example, only marsupial mammals in Australia, or animals native to volcanic islands are only animals that could have gotten across water (birds, reptile eggs that could float), whereas large land mammals are native to continental islands that we're long ago connected to land.

Answer (score 1):

The entire survival and spread of people and animals after they left the ark was by a miracle. For example, there was not enough of any species in the ark to allow for a critical mass for the next generation to survive. Consider the passenger pigeon which became extinct when the flock size dropped below the millions within historical times. Thus, both the survival and the spread to the rest of the world was by a miracle. See also the posts on this site about the food required that was available only by a miracle. As soon as a meat eating animal would have eaten a pig, the entire species would have disappeared had they not first built up a full population miraculously.